# Rasa: Can actions return payload data objects?

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I want my Rasa bot to reply with only a payload data object (similar to common JSON objects) instead of uttering anything (*utterance is not important in this case*).

Can custom actions do this? How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want raw JSON to be displayed in the conversations?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, RASA has `utter_custom_json()` method for the same which you can call from a custom action.
See the `CollectingDispatcher` class [code](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-sdk/blob/master/rasa_sdk/executor.py) here. 
There is [same question](https://forum.rasa.com/t/can-custom-actions-return-payload-data-objects-json/17301) on RASA forum

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. This code should be placed in `actions.py`. Your json payload should be passed as `buttons`.

```
dispatcher.utter_button_message(
    'some text that can be ignored', buttons
)
```

You can also take a look at how this function is implemented here: [rasa-sdk on GitHub](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-sdk/blob/master/rasa_sdk/executor.py)